# Will call an async function recursively fill up the stack?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, recursion

I have the following function. Sorry it's a little long... but there isn't really much to it.
It's a simple function that will cycle through messages, and send them through websockets.

The most crucial part, and the crux of this question, is: will this line cause the stack to fill up?

```
// through this loop
sendMessagesInTab( tabId, cb );
```

...? Basically, by the time the cycle is finished, more records might have been added to the list. Since this function will only ever run once (there is a semaphore there, `currentlyDeliveringTab[ tabId ]`), when it finishes I want to check again that nothing was added to the list. To do that I use the function itself.

From my testing, I haven't actually managed to fill up the stack. I assume that's because this is not 'recursion' since everything is async. But I am baffled: will this use up all of the available memory if things are added *all* of the time?

```
function sendMessagesInTab( tabId, cb ){

  consolelog("Entered sendMessagesInTab for tab", tabId);

  // Semaphore. Only one instance of this is to run at any given time
  if( currentlyDeliveringTab[ tabId ] ){
    consolelog("Already running for tab ", tabId);
    return;
  }
  currentlyDeliveringTab[ tabId ] = true;

  consolelog("Looking up tab...");
  stores.tabs.dbLayer.selectById( tabId, function( err, tab ){
    if( err ){
      delete currentlyDeliveringTab[ tabId ];
      return cb( err );
    }
    if( ! tab ){
      delete currentlyDeliveringTab[ tabId ];
      return new Error("tabId not found!");
    }


    stores.tabMessages.dbLayer.selectByHash( { tabId: tabId }, function( err, tabMessages ){
      if( err ){
        delete currentlyDeliveringTab[ tabId ];
        return cb( err );
      }


      if( !tabMessages.length ){
        consolelog("No messages to be delivered, that's it...");
        delete currentlyDeliveringTab[ tabId ];
        return cb( null );
      }


      /*
      // TESTING RECURSION
      delete currentlyDeliveringTab[ tabId ];
      return sendMessagesInTab( tabId, function(err ) { console.log("ERROR:", err ) } );
      */

      consolelog("There are messages to be delivered:", tabId, tabMessages.length );
      async.eachSeries(

        tabMessages,

        function( record, cb ){

          consolelog("Checking the connection...");

          // If the connection is not there, all good but "false" (delivery failed)
          var ws = connections[ record.tabId ] && connections[ record.tabId ].ws;
          if( ! ws ) return cb( new Error("No websocket connection") ); // End of cycle will kill currentlyDeliveringTab

          var message = record.message;
          message.messageId = record.id;

          // Attempt delivery over websocket. If it works, great. If it doesn't,
          // sorry.
          consolelog("Attempt to stringify the message", tabId);
          try {
            var strMessage = JSON.stringify( message );
          } catch ( err ){
            return cb( err );
          }

          consolelog("Sending message through the websocket", tabId);
          ws.send( strMessage, function( err ){
            if( err ) return cb( err ); // End of cycle will kill currentlyDeliveringTab

            consolelog("Deleting the message", tabId);

            stores.tabMessages.dbLayer.deleteById( record.id, function( err ){
              if( err ) return cb( err ); // End of cycle will kill currentlyDeliveringTab

              consolelog("Updating lastSync", tabId);

              cb( null );
            });
          })
        },

        function( err ){
          if( err ){
            consolelog("ERROR!", err );
            delete currentlyDeliveringTab[ tabId ];
            return cb( err );
          }

          consolelog("All messages have been sent successfully!");
          consolelog("Now running sendMessagesInTab again in case messages were added WHILE sending these");
          delete currentlyDeliveringTab[ tabId ];

          // Rerun sendMessagesInTab to check that messages weren't added while going
          // through this loop
          sendMessagesInTab( tabId, cb );
        }
      );

    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will call an async function recursively fill up the stack?

No, it will not cause any stack build up if it is called from an async callback.  When you execute an asynchronous function and then return control back to the system (while waiting for the callback to be called), the current thread of execution has completed and thus the stack is emptied and then a completely new stack is initiated when the completion event for the asynchronous operation is fired which will then trigger your completion callback.

Keep in mind one thing that is different in Javascript compared to a language like C/C++ is that function scopes and the objects in the function scope are garbage collected entities and are not on the stack.  So, you can have a closure surrounding an async callback that is still alive even though the thread of execution has completely unwound and cleared the stack.  The elements in a function scope are garbage collected (similar to other objects in Javascript) when it is no longer reachable by any active code.  So, it stays alive while an async callback can still happen, but once that callback occurs and can no longer occur again, then everything in the scope is eligible for garbage collection.

But as soon as an async callback is called and the callback finishes executing, that local scope should be GCed. It would be an unusual situation to get a buildup of local scopes unless you continue to add more and more event handlers that are still alive and could be called. If the event handlers can no longer be called (because the internal object that initiated them is itself done), then the items in the scope are unreachable and will be eligible for GC.

Comment: What about variables in the local scope of the *caller*? I mean, even if it's async, variable scoping rules still apply... surely. Or am I jsut getting worked up about nothing here?

Comment: @Merc - Coincidentially, I just added a paragraph to my answer about variables in a function scope.

Comment: Why the downvote?  If you think something in this answer is not correct, then please explain what you think is not correct!

Comment: I upvoted to balance the downvote, sorry I have no idea who or why would downvote it.

Comment: Back to your question: OK, so it won't affect the stack, but it might well affect memory consumption... which I can fix by making sure all variables are defined OUTSIDE of that (so that nothing is effectively allocated) whenever possible... right?

Comment: I mean, ideally, if I wanted to make sure I don't eat up memory constantly, I would have to write this differently... but how? Or maybe there is no need?

Comment: @Merc - But as soon as an async callback is called and the callback finishes executing, that local scope should be GCed.  It would be an unusual situation to get a buildup of local scopes unless you continue to add more and more event handlers that are still alive and could be called.  If the event handlers can no longer be called (because the internal object that initiated them is itself done), then the items in the scope are unreachable and will be eligible for GC.

Comment: @Merc - There should be no need to change from your general concept.  This is used a lot in node.js to execute something recurringly after the prior operation finishes.

Comment: "But as soon as an async callback is called and the callback finishes executing, that local scope should be GCed" Oh MY GOD OF COURSE!!! What an idiot I am! And... thank you!

Comment: Sometimes I feel I should be a barman. Or a bricklayer. You know... Thanks for your help :D

Comment: On a more useful note, maybe add this to the answer: "- But as soon as an async callback is called and the callback finishes executing, that local scope should be GCed. It would be an unusual situation to get a buildup of local scopes unless you continue to add more and more event handlers that are still alive and could be called. If the event handlers can no longer be called (because the internal object that initiated them is itself done), then the items in the scope are unreachable and will be eligible for GC."

Comment: @Merc - I added it.